# Android(Eclipse) deleting project completely

Tags: android, project

Recently I found that after deleting project (in Eclipse) from `workspace` directory and from `<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\` it still exist in emulator and I can simply run it. So how can I completely delete project?

Comment: emulator has apk not the project.

Comment: Also it exist after deleting all files that search return for projectname

Comment: ok, how I can delete apk file?

Comment: Settings->App-> uninstall

Comment: thanks for help I will check it and answer you

Comment: emm, but I can't find Settings submenu in Eclipse it have only Search and Source

Comment: :D search your emulator dear :)

Comment: It works! So all what I need do to delete a project is to delete it from `workspace`,  delete all folders and files from `<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\` and delete apk from emulator?

Comment: lol, that was epic fail :D just need to sleep